# Bot didn't start on my Wordpress site

Tags: smooch

I did a bot on Chatfuel and integrate it with Smooch through the wordpress plugin. Everything is ok in the setting (Token) BUT the Chat didn't start and when I answer nothing happen.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to somehow connect your Chatfuel bot into Smooch since there's currently not per built integration between Chatfuel and Smooch.

Using Chatfuel's [JSON API](https://help.chatfuel.com/facebook-messenger/plugins/json-plugin/) and [Smooch API](https://docs.smooch.io/rest/#introduction) and [webhooks](https://docs.smooch.io/rest/#webhooks) it should be possible to integrate the two platform.

Alternatively, you can use one of the other [Bot platform integration](https://app.smooch.io/integrations/categories/bot-platform) that is already available on Smooch